# Differences between Promise.all usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Here are what I thought were 3 identical operations.  The third one however, results in no output and I don't understand why.  Can someone please explain?

```
    await Promise.all(["foo 1", "bar 1"].map(async item => console.log(item)));
> foo 1
> bar 1

    const print = async (item) => console.log(item);
    await Promise.all([
        print("foo 2"),
        print("bar 2")
    ]);
> foo 2
> bar 2

    await Promise.all([
        async () => console.log("foo 3"),
        async () => console.log("bar 3")
    ]);
[no output]
```

(using nodejs v10.19.0)

Comment: You're supposed to pass an Array of `Promise`s to `Promise.all`. You never call those Anonymous `async` functions in your last example, so they never return a `Promise`. Should be like `await Promise.all([(async ()=>{ console.log('foo 3'); })(), (async ()=>{ console.log('bar 3'); })()]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last example, you are passing 2 async functions. Awaiting a function doesn't really make sense, you need to await the *result* of the function, and to do that you need to call it.

```
await Promise.all([
    (async () => console.log("foo 3"))(),
    (async () => console.log("bar 3"))()
]);
```

Comment: But, there's no point in wrapping a synchronous function like this in an async wrapper either.

Comment: @jfriend00 all of the code samples appear to be just for testing, so i wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

All that `Promise.all` does is it waits for Promises to resolve. It does not call functions, other than `.then`s chained into it.

Your first code:

```
await Promise.all(["foo 1", "bar 1"].map(async item => console.log(item)));
```

is equivalent to:

```
const promises = ["foo 1", "bar 1"].map(async item => console.log(item));
await Promise.all(promises);
```

The `console.log`s result from the invoking of `.map`. (The `.map` also happens to produce an array of Promises.)

Your second code:

```
const print = async (item) => console.log(item);
await Promise.all([
    print("foo 2"),
    print("bar 2")
]);
```

is equivalent to:

```
const print = async (item) => console.log(item);
const promises = [
    print("foo 2"),
    print("bar 2")
];
await Promise.all(promises);
```

The `console.log`s result from the *invoking* of `print` inside the array literal. (It also happens to produce an array of Promises.)

In your third code:

```
await Promise.all([
    async () => console.log("foo 3"),
    async () => console.log("bar 3")
]);
```

No functions are being invoked, other than `Promise.all`, so nothing gets logged. You've passed an array of functions to `Promise.all`, and `Promise.all` will not invoke those functions.